# Symfony 1.4 - Pass URL in get request

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I want to redirect the previous page after the login. My first question is what is the best solution for it?

I try following solution. 
send previous page url in get request and redirect to the url that in get request.

This is my previous page action.

```
public function executeVotes(sfWebRequest $request)
{
        $chaletId = (int) $request->getParameter('id');
        $this->rates = (int) $request->getParameter('rates', 0);

        if (
            ($this->getUser()->isAuthenticated() === FALSE )
            || ($this->getUser()->hasCredential('member_permission') === FALSE)
        ) {
            $this->redirect('member_signin', array(
                'redirect' => $this->getController()->genUrl('chalet_votes/' . $chaletId . '/?rates=' . $this->rates, true)
            ));
        }
}
```

This is my signin action

```
public function executeSignin(sfWebRequest $request)
{
        $this->redirectUrl = $this->getRequest()->getParameter('redirect');

        echo $this->redirectUrl; die;
}
```

This is routers for these actions.

```
member_signin:
  url: /member/login/*
  param: { module: member, action: signin}

votes:
  url: /chalet/votes/:id
  param: { module: test, action: votes }
```

This is url after redirect to the signin page.

```
http://test.dev/member/login/redirect/http%3A%2F%2Fchalet.dev%2Fchalet_votes%2F1%2Frates%2F9
```

My server show 404 page error. What is the issue? How can i do it?

Comment: Why not storing the previous URL into a `SESSION` variable???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of redirecting the non-authenticated user to the `member_signin`. Try forwarding them:

```
$this->forward('member_signin');
```

Because you're not redirecting, when you post the sign-in form, you will have the referrer URL available in the `$request->getReferer()` method.

So what you'll need to do in your signin action:

```
public function executeSignin(sfWebRequest $request)
{
    $user = $this->getUser();

    // If the user has been authenticated, helps prevent redirect loop as well.
    if ($user->isAuthenticated()) {
        $this->redirect('@defaultpage');
    }

    // Do authentication
    //...

    // If authenticated
    $this->redirect($request->getReferer());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work.

```
$this->redirect('member_signin', array(
    'redirect' => urlencode($this->getController()->genUrl('chalet_votes/' . $chaletId . '/?rates=' . $this->rates, true))
));
```

Note the `urlencode()`. So dont forget to use `urldecode()` on url before redirecting.

You can also use session to save url, but remember to unset it from session once redirected after login to prevent redirect loop.

Hope this helps.